# Making ncurses work with Qt qtextstream

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ncurses, qtextstream

I'm currently trying to make a Qt console program work with ncurses. I would like to enjoy the advantages of ncurses while still being able to use QTextStream for input and output.

The idea is to use `while((c = getch()).....` for one particular type of input, while using `QTextStream(stdin)` for other types of input.

The thing is, if I proceed as follows:

```
initscr();
//do ncurses stuff
//do QTextStream(stdout) stuff
//do QTextStream(stdin) stuff
```

I get the following result:[image]

However, if I do this:

```
initscr();
//do ncurses stuff
endwin();
//do QTextStream(stdout) stuff
//do QTextStream(stdin) stuff
```

The result looks much more appropriate:
[image]

My question is if the same result can be achieved without the repeated calling of `initscr();` and `endwin();` every time I want to receive a specific type of input (this is dome relatively often in the program). And if not, are there any pitfalls to this? I know it definitely is not a decent programming practice, but can it have consequences beyond that? The effect on performance is not noticable, at least.

Comment: If you have any specific questions/aspects that make this not a duplicate, let us know by editing your question to deduplicate it.

Comment: So, will using the approach you have linked have no adverse effects on how QTextStream works? Will its output be placed correctly, like in the second image?

Comment: Just try it. It works at least for the simple output I've tried it with. If you have a more complex case, you probably should reimplement the message handler to use `printw()` or somesuch instead of suspending curses like you do. Also since you presumably don't integrate with event loop, so your code will be very awkward. In any case, you should add a simple test case to your question that demonstrates the issue (if it's longer than 100 lines, you're doing it wrong).

Comment: Actually: (1) he's asking a different question and (2) I'm unconvinced that your answer is correct.